# Is a solvable group satisfying a semigroup law?

Tags: gr.group-theory, semigroups-and-monoids, solvable-groups

Let $S$ be the free semigroup on the set $\{x_1,\ldots ,x_n\}$, where $n$ is a positive integer. Suppose that $\mu=\mu (x_1,\ldots ,x_n)$ and $\nu = \nu (x_1,\ldots ,x_n)$ are two elements in $S$. We say that $\mu=\nu$ is a *semigroup law* in a group $G$ if for every $n$-tuple $(g_1,\ldots , g_n)$ of elements of $G$, we have $\mu (g_1,\ldots , g_n)=\nu (g_1,\ldots , g_n)$.

For example an Abelian group satisfies the semigroup law $\mu=\nu$ where $\mu (x_1,x_2)=x_1x_2$ and $\nu (x_1,x_2)=x_2x_1$. And similarly for nilpotent groups of class $c$ we can find a finite sequence of semigroup laws $\mu_1=\nu_1,\ldots,\mu_c=\nu_c$.

Now I am looking for semigroup laws that solvable groups are expressible by them.

Comment: You write "expressible by a semigroup law" but this is confusing, it should be "satisfying a semigroup law". Indeed the law is far from characterizing the group, as the verb "express" suggests.

Comment: Thanks for your comment,  I changed it @YCor

Comment: Note also that "expressible by a set $S$ of semigroup law" could make sense, but not for a group, rather for a class $C$ of groups, namely $C$ would be exactly the class of groups satisfying all laws in $S$. For instance, abelian (=1-step-nilpotent) groups are those satisfying $xy=yx$, and $c$-step-nilpotent groups (=those of class $\le c$) are those satisfying a certain finite set of semigroup laws, if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 12):

The generators of a free metabelian group of rank two generate a free subsemigroup so there is no semigroup law defining solvable of  derived length 2. Much smaller metabelian groups, like the lamplighter group, also have free subsemigroups of rank 2.

**Update.** It is proved in
J. A. Lewin and T. Lewin,' Semigroup laws in varieties of solvable groups', Proc. Cambridge Philos. 5oc. 65(1969), 1-9 that a finitely generated solvable group satisfies a semigroup law iff it is virtually nilpotent so the answer is no in an extreme sense.

**Update 2.** As pointed out by @YCor, Rosenblatt proved a finitely generated solvable group that is not virtually nilpotent (or in the paper he works with polynomial growth) has a free subsemigroup on two generators.  The reference can be found in the comments.

Comment: Rosenblatt (1974) even improved the latter fact, showing that any non-virtually-nilpotent f.g. solvable group contains a free subsemigroup on 2 elements (and hence on $k$ elements for any $k$). [DOI link pointing to AMS site](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9947-1974-0342955-9)

Comment: @YCor,  I had forgotten that.  Thanks